# Appium_Error : Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement with Xcode 10.0

Tags: mobile, appium, appium-ios

Getting the error 'Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement'

Xcode Version : 10.0 
Appium Server Version : 1.9.1 / 1.13.0
Appium Client Version : 6.1.0 / 7.0.0
Selenium Version : 3.9.1 / 3.14.0
IOS Simulator Version : 11.4

Have tried with different versions as below:
Appium Server version : from 1.7.2 to 1.14.2 beta
Appium Client version : 5.0.4 to 7.0.0
Also tried to include implicit wait and explicit waits as well. No luck :(

**Appium Logs Client Side as below:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.11.0
Jul 01, 2019 10:34:30 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setupDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=2B000000-0000-0000-777A-000000000000, ELEMENT=2B000000-0000-0000-777A-000000000000}
Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'
System info: host: 'Bindacharyas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c4b:5bdc:c1c1:72f2%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:421)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.FindsByAccessibilityId.findElementByAccessibilityId(FindsByAccessibilityId.java:31)
at com.noon.ui.tests.sanitySuites.TestIOSAnother.prepareIOSForAppium(TestIOSAnother.java:103)
at com.noon.ui.tests.sanitySuites.TestIOSAnother.setupDriver(TestIOSAnother.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:419)
... 25 more
```

Few Lines of Code as below:

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 6s Plus");
        capabilities.setCapability("wdaStartupRetries", 5);
        capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 250);

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.4");

        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/bindacharyaj/Documents/Simulator/k12App-ios.app");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "777EA4A8-0C82-485D-8347-8EF3527B135A");

        capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "com.noonEdu.k12App");
        capabilities.setCapability("updatedWDABundleId", "com.facebook.wda.lib");
        capabilities.setCapability("wdaLocalPort", 8101);

        driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(url, capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(driver.getContext());
        driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

    }

    // 6
    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void myFirstTest() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(000);

        System.out.println("Test Started");


        ((WebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='السعودية']"))).click();
        System.out.println("Click -1");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Appium launches the app but not able to click on any of the native elements.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance... !!!!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. I need some more info to try to help you. How do you access to the element? can you show us some lines of your code? Yo can edit your post to show it to us.

Comment: public static By element = By.xpath(
  "//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name='نون أكاديمي']

 capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);

 iosDriver = new IOSDriver(new URL(APPIUM_SERVER_URL), capabilities);
 iosDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 Thread.sleep(5000);
(MobileElement) iosDriver.findElement(element).click();

Comment: Logs from Appium Client Side :               FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setupDriver org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=2B000000-0000-0000-777A-000000000000, ELEMENT=2B000000-0000-0000-777A-000000000000} Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'

Comment: @rcarba : Any help here please

Comment: Please, edit your post and add there the info you provide on the comments.

Comment: Updated the code with client level logs and also few lines of code as well ...@rcarba..Please do help!!

Comment: Issue got resolved with Eclipse cache problem.
Had to remove.m2 completely and re-built the project again and used Xcode 10.2.1 version